# What is the difference between ISO BMFF and other mp4 format?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, media-source

As about.
I want to play a MP4 via Media Source Extensions, but not any MP4 file can play. Please check [FLV.js](https://github.com/Bilibili/flv.js), it works by transmuxing FLV file stream into ISO BMFF (Fragmented MP4) segments, followed by feeding mp4 segments into an HTML5  element through Media Source Extensions API.

So, What is the diference between ISO BMFF and other mp4 format?

Comment: essentially nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer from following links.

https://www.w3.org/2013/12/byte-stream-format-registry/isobmff-byte-stream-format.html

https://www.w3.org/TR/media-source/

Comment: iSO BMFF is a segment mp4, one segment === moof + mdat